# No entry is registered for key 'db'

Tags: zend-db

Other program written an application in ZEND. I want to install that application to another server. 
When I install the application it has following error, I checked the forums. They said to install pdo_mysql.. then I installed that in server but no use. Still have same error.

exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'No entry is registered for key 'db'' in /usr/share/php/Zend/Registry.php:147
Stack trace:

0 /home/dev/public_html/medtranscloud.com/library/MT/DatabaseModel.php(29): Zend_Registry::get('db')
1 /home/dev/public_html/medtranscloud.com/library/Entity/Page.php(119): MT_DatabaseModel::db()
2 /home/dev/public_html/medtranscloud.com/modules/site/controllers/ErrorController.php(23): Entity_Page::getMenuItems()
3 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Action.php(513): Site_ErrorController->errAction()
4 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(289): end_Controller_Action->dispatch('errAction')
5 /usr/share/php/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
6 /home/dev/public_html/medtranscloud.com/Bootstrap.php(21): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
7 /home/dev/public_html/medtranscloud.com/public/index.php(7): Bootstrap::run()
8 {main}

Also I have used config.xml for db configuratrion. not application.ini

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very specific error which can only be solved by you, by going through the code.
The exception says that there is no value registered with the name key 'db'.

Most likely, your Bootstrap (or loaded resource) is responsible for actually bootstrapping the db adapter and adding it to the Zend_Registry. You might want to look inside `/home/dev/public_html/medtranscloud.com/Bootstrap.php` and work your way forward from there.